# How do I set up my environment for ESC/Java2 in Windows and build/run with ESC/Java2?

Tags: java, jml

How do I set up my execution environment for ESC/Java2 in WindowsXP? And furthermore, how do I build and run, in WindowsXP, projects with ESC/Java2. It is hard to tell from their specifications/readme and documentation, specially considering the fact that they seem to be talking more about Unix based operating systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Eclipse Europa](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/) (3.3) (or higher, at your own risk...most plugins are upwards-compatibile) and its associated [Eclipse Plugin](http://kind.ucd.ie/products/opensource/ESCJava2/escjava-eclipse/updates/).

To install a plugin, go to help->Software Updates->Find and Install, then add a new remote site from the plugin's update site.  You can then select the plugin to install, and click through the "ok" prompts.  Restart Eclipse and it should be installed then.